# Bazel unable to build external Rust dependency with feature serde1

Tags: bazel, rust-cargo, bazel-rules

I'm trying to include [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/) as an external dependency in my repository. In particular, I want its `forge` cli command in [github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/cli](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/cli/Cargo.toml#L106-L109).

I've set up a WORKSPACE file that includes the CLI's crates and a bit more:

```
crates_repository(
    name = "foundry",
    annotations = {
        "svm-rs": [crate.annotation(
            gen_binaries = True,
        )],
        "foundry-cli": [crate.annotation(
            gen_binaries = True,
        )],
        "forge": [crate.annotation(
            gen_binaries = True,
        )],
        "serde": [crate.annotation(
            gen_binaries = True,
        )],
    },
    cargo_lockfile = "//:Cargo.lock",
    lockfile = "//:Cargo.Bazel.lock",
    packages = {
        "svm-rs": crate.spec(
            git = "https://github.com/alloy-rs/svm-rs",
            rev = "b55c47b09437cf8dc01e1028aa0ab0a2300083d4",
        ),
        "forge": crate.spec(
            git = "https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry",
            rev = "d5db2c514fea76291715b019db65b60aa41eb421",
        ),
        "foundry-cli": crate.spec(
            git = "https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry",
            rev = "d5db2c514fea76291715b019db65b60aa41eb421",
        ),
        "serde": crate.spec(
            version = "1",
            features = ["derive"],
        ),
        #### Added the below while debugging
        "camino": crate.spec(
            version = "1.1.6",
            features = ["serde1"],
        ),
        "globset": crate.spec(
            version = "0.4.9",
            features = ["serde1"],
        ),
        "serde_derive": crate.spec(
            version = "1",
        ),
        "serde_json": crate.spec(
            version = "1",
        ),
        "hex": crate.spec(
            features = ["serde"],
        ),
        ### end of added
    },
)
```

I then need to change a generated rule in `.cache/bazel/_bazel_j/6c68e123d5be80edfb5e3a8f56f57687/external/foundry__svm-rs-0.3.0/BUILD.bazel` from

```
rust_binary(
    name = "svm__bin",
    ...
```

to

```
rust_binary(
    name = "svm",
    ...
```

then when trying to run `bazel build @foundry//:foundry-cli__forge` I then get the following:

```
ERROR: .cache/bazel/_bazel_j/6c68e123d5be80edfb5e3a8f56f57687/external/foundry__camino-1.1.6/BUILD.bazel:22:13: Compiling Rust rlib camino v1.1.6 (6 files) failed: (Exit 1): process_wrapper failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_rust/util/process_wrapper/process_wrapper --env-file bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/foundry__camino-1.1.6/camino_build_script.env --arg-file ... (remaining 35 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
error: proc-macro derive panicked
   --> external/foundry__camino-1.1.6/src/lib.rs:108:39
    |
108 | #[cfg_attr(feature = "serde1", derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize))]
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: message: file missing from serde_derive manifest directory during macro expansion: .cache/bazel/_bazel_j/6c68e123d5be80edfb5e3a8f56f57687/sandbox/linux-sandbox/7574/execroot/external/foundry__serde_derive-1.0.183/serde_derive-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

error: proc-macro derive panicked
   --> external/foundry__camino-1.1.6/src/lib.rs:108:57
    |
108 | #[cfg_attr(feature = "serde1", derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize))]
    |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: message: file missing from serde_derive manifest directory during macro expansion: .cache/bazel/_bazel_j/6c68e123d5be80edfb5e3a8f56f57687/sandbox/linux-sandbox/7574/execroot/external/foundry__serde_derive-1.0.183/serde_derive-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `deserialize` found for struct `Utf8PathBuf` in the current scope
   --> external/foundry__camino-1.1.6/src/serde_impls.rs:62:25
    |
62  |         Ok(Utf8PathBuf::deserialize(deserializer)?.into())
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Utf8PathBuf`
    |
   ::: external/foundry__camino-1.1.6/src/lib.rs:111:1
    |
111 | pub struct Utf8PathBuf(PathBuf);
    | ---------------------- function or associated item `deserialize` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
    = note: the following traits define an item `deserialize`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
            candidate #1: `Deserialize`
            candidate #2: `DeserializeSeed`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

It looks like I'm missing `serde1` since `Deserialize` and `DeserializeSeed` are both part of serde1 according to https://serde.rs/derive.html, but I thought I'm already including the `serde1` feature - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open bug with `serde_derive` and `rules_rust`: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/issues/2071#issuecomment-1656204269

Pinning my package version with the below fixed this

```
"serde": crate.spec(
  features = ["derive"],
  version = "=1.0.164",
),
```